# String replace removing the pipe delimiter

Tags: java, string

I am having one string and it contains the | delimiter with it. I want to replace the \t,\n \r with space in java but not |.

```
String str="Hello|MyDear|";
str.replaceAll("[\\t|\\r|\\n]+","");
```

I am expecting that my string will remain same but i am getting value of str as `HelloMydear`

is my regex is not correct or where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Strings are immutatble, `str = str.replaceAll("[\\t|\\r|\\n]+","");`

Comment: Your current character class includes the pipe character.  You don't OR in regex using `|`.  Note that your input also doesn't even contain `\n` etc.

Answer (score 2):

First, `\n` and the other control characters do not require double escaped backslash.  Second, your alternation is wrong and does not mean what you intend.  Just put the control characters directly into the alternation:

```java
String str = "Hello\t|MyDear\n|";
String output = str.replaceAll("[\t\r\n]+", "");
System.out.println(output);  // Hello|MyDear|
```